# Use monitor as portrait mode using Miracast

Tags: chromecast, external-display, screencast, miracast, screen-mirroring

I want to cast my mobile screen to an LED monitor which has an HDMI port using [Miracast](https://www.amazon.in/Wireless-Miracast-Screen-Mirroring-Connector/dp/B09KLX2BQ7/ref=mp_s_a_1_5?crid=31YHO8W1B14AX&keywords=miracast&qid=1642533328&sprefix=miracas%2Caps%2C484&sr=8-5). The device is not purchased, But the testing is done by an Android TV now.

If the mobile is in landscape mode, the monitor will be filled with the mobile screen content. But I need to use the monitor in portrait mode permanently with the mobile also in portrait mode. Is there any way to rotate the casted content by -90 degrees?

**Mobile content**

[image]

**Actual result in monitor**
[image]

**Required result in monitor**
[image]

I am using two mobile phones for casting with the Google home application

**1. Lenovo P2 (Android 7)**

**2. LG Q6 (Android 8.1)**

Also while testing the mirroring, I felt there is a delay appears in the TV. Also, the text is blurred on the screen.

Note: I can see some similar questions are there, but nothing seems helpful.

Comment: I noticed your comment on [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/138973/44325) (that I've deleted, please don't post a comment under someone's post requesting personal help). Have you tried it? Also, how about [the other answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/212247/44325)? Mentioning "nothing seems helpful" is kind of confusing since we don't know which answers have you read and tried...

Comment: I have the same problem, have you solved it anyway? thanks