# Show Full Screen Portrait Layout with a VERTICAL screen with miracast

Tags: android-tv, external-display, miracast

I have read [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/35402/show-fullscreen-portrait-layout-with-miracast?newreg=98875ef31d6c4992865d63ad9f51f7fb) and understand it is obviously not a smart idea to display the portrait layout on a horizontal (say 16:9) screen. However, many newer screens are able to rotate up (to 9:16) so I wonder if there is any short cuts to display the same portrait layout on such a screen, just like the one in this ad (which sells for $600 while we can buy a standard tiny 2.4G miracast receiver for less than $20).

[image: ha]